# Why this nested ng-include won't display results

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on a website and to reuse the layout on some pages I've used the `angularjs` `ng-include` `directive` to achieve this.

1. I have an `ng-include` on my `hrFormReviewDetails.html` page that includes my `starter.html`.
2. I then have an `ng-include` on my `payrollFormReviewDetails.html` and this includes the `hrFormReviewDetails.html` page.

The following image represents the approach to my issue:

[image: Architecture]

The 1st `ng-include` for `starter.html` works as expected, however, the 2nd `ng-include` that includes `hrFormReviewDetails.html` doesn't work.

The `hrFormReviewDetails.html` page is used to load in the details submitted from the `starter.html` page and specific details needed to complete the `hrFormReviewDetails.html` form. **This approach works fine.**

The `payrollFormReviewDetails.html` page is used to load in the details submitted from the `starter.html` AND `hrFormReviewDetails.html` page. Specific details are then needed to complete the `payrollFormReviewDetails.html` form.
**This is not working.**

What I get is the `starter.html` and `hrFormReviewDetails.html` page loaded into the `payrollFormReviewDetails.html` page but no data is being loaded into the `html` fields. I'm getting no console errors.

My questions is, can you load multiple `html` pages that already have a `html` page using the `ng-directive`?

**Code Snippets:**

**`starter.html`:**

```
<form name="newStartForm" ng-submit="saveNewStarterForm(newStartForm.$valid)" novalidate autocomplete="off">

    <!-- Section to contain the employee details for the new start -->
    <div class="form-control">

            <h3>EMPLOYEE DETAILS</h3>
            <div class="margin-bottom-small"><small><strong>Fields marked with an asterisk (*) are required.</strong></small></div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'alert alert-danger': newStartForm.$submitted && newStartForm.title.$invalid}">
                <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><strong>*</strong> Title:</label>
                <select id="title" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" ng-model="newStart.title" name="title" required>
                    <option disabled value="">Select a title...</option>
                    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                </select>
            </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**`hrFormReviewDetails.html`:**

```
<form name="newStartForm" ng-submit="saveHrNewStarterReviewForm(newStartForm.$valid)" novalidate autocomplete="off">

    <div ng-include="'views/starter.html'"></div>

    <div class="form-control form-margin-top">

            <h3>NOTES FROM HR :- RETAIL / PRIMAL</h3>

            <div id="hourly-rate-container" class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">Hourly Rate (£): </label>
                <input id="hourlyRate" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" type="text" ng-model="newStart.hourlyRate" ng-keypress="preventNonNumericalInputWithDecimal()" name="hourlyRate" />
            </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

**`payrollFormReviewDetails.html`:**

```
<form name="newStartForm" ng-submit="savePayrollNewStarterReviewForm(newStartForm.$valid)" novalidate autocomplete="off">

    <div ng-include="'views/hrFormReviewDetails.html'"></div>

    <div class="form-control form-margin-top">
        <div class="center">
            <h3>FAO PAYROLL:</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">Sage Pay Reference: </label>
                <input id="sagePayReference" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" type="text" ng-model="newStart.sagePayReference" name="sagePayReference" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">Pension Type: </label>
                <input id="pensionType" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" type="text" ng-model="newStart.pensionType" name="pensionType" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**NB:** this is a condensed version of each of the `html` pages.

Comment: Could you please provide your working code?

Comment: Code snippets added.